# Low frequency waves influence of high frequency waves

Tags: waves, signal-processing

If I have a 20 MHz surface wave travelling along a material, and then introduce a 50 or 100 Hz wave source, will there be a noticeable difference to the output?

(Surface acoustic wave type device, for generating and detecting the waves, lower frequency wave with other mechanism)

If the surface wave velocity is 4 km/s, the 20 MHz has a wavelength of 200 um and a 100 Hz wavelength would be 40 m.
So would I be right in thinking that these are not really comparable? And a set up to measure 20 MHz would not detect a surface wave with such a low frequency and no change would be detected in the output?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: To what type of waves are you referring?  Meaning, are these acoustic waves in a solid material or electromagnetic waves excited on the surface?

Comment: Theoretically, the resulting wave is $20 MHz +/- 100 Hz$. Practically, how can you measure it? For example, Surface Waves transducers will filter out this low frequency.

Comment: They would be acoustic waves on a (piezoelectric) solid, honeste_vivere. And thank you npojo, that was my thinking with the filtering and I am not sure it could be measured practically. What if I could include a 5 MHz wave now, wavelength 800 um, I should also see the 5 MHz appear at the output, provided there are enough IDTs for the wavelength?

Comment: I tend to modify my previous response. IDT will not pass $100 Hz$ but actually ***will*** pass $20MHz +/- 100 Hz$. So the question is whether your spectrum analyser can resolve $10 Hz$ on top of $20MHz$. As for $5MHz$, it depends on the bandwidth of the IDT. I am not sure why you "retreat" to wavelength discussions.

Comment: By the way, you should tag a name from whom you want response. e.g. @npojo.

Comment: @npojo thank you for your response and discussion it has been helpful. The "retreat" to wavelength discussion is due to inexperience and how I have been visualising things in my head.  And thank you for the tip to tag a name.